# React Admin add a button beside create button

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to add a new button called bulk upload beside **create button**, clicking on that button will take user to a form, from where user can upload a file.

[image]

Comment: @hellogoodnight, I am new to react-admin can you write me a example source code. thanks in advance.

Comment: @hellogoodnight, indeed, that's good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ah!!! it was easy: adding a tool bar solve my problem.

```
const ListActions = (props) => {
  const { className, basePath } = props;
  return (
    <TopToolbar className={className}>
      <BulkUploadButton></BulkUploadButton>
      <CreateButton basePath={basePath} />
    </TopToolbar>
  );
};

<List {...props} filters={<TagFilter />} actions={<ListActions />} >
```